# поиск первой заглавной буквы английского алфавита в строке

Tags: sql

Нужно найти в строках когда первый раз когда встречается заглавная буква английского алфавита
образно говоря это должно выглядеть как-то так
`select charindex([A-Z],name ) from tablica`
то есть к примеру должно выводить порядковый номер буквы G  в приложении Резиновый коврик в багажник Gledring
ну или букву порядковый номер буквы W в другом предложении на скрине
[image]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение для MS SQL Server.

Примечательные моменты:

- Использование типа данных столбца `NVARCHAR(...)`
- Использование функции `PATINDEX()`
- Использование правильного COLLATION.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и пример заполнения данных, начaло
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, words NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (words) VALUES
(N'Ствол дерева Glider'),
(N'Собака is Barking');
-- DDL и пример заполнения данных, конец

SELECT * 
    , PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', words COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) AS FirstCapitalLetterPosition
FROM @tbl;
```

**Результат**

| ID | words | FirstCapitalLetterPosition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ствол дерева Glider | 14 |
| 2 | Собака is Barking | 11 |